# SBT creates two target folders. Is this normal?

Tags: scala, sbt

I do not have a build.sbt in my root directory but I do have a `Build.scala` file in my `project` folder. For some reason two `target` folders are generated when compiling (one under `project` and one in root).

Is this behavior normal? If not, how can I fix it? If so, will telling `.sbt` to generate these folders/files under one folder cause any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal.

The `target` in your root is target for your project. The `target` in the `project` directory is a `target` for the build definition, which itself is compiled by SBT.

[SBT is recursive.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive)

> The project directory is another project inside your project which
>   knows how to build your project. The project inside project can (in
>   theory) do anything any other project can do. Your build definition is
>   an sbt project.